# Implementing a priority queue in matlab in order to solve optimization problems using BRANCH AND BOUND

Tags: matlab, priority-queue

I'm trying to code a priority queue in MATLAB, I know there is the SIMULINK toolbox for priority queue, but I'm trying to code it in MATLAB. I have a pseudo code that uses priority queue for a method called BEST First Search with Branch and Bound. The branch and bound algorithm design strategy is a state space tree and it is used to solve optimization problems. [simple explanation of what is branch and bound](http://optlab-server.sce.carleton.ca/POAnimations2007/BranchAndBound.html)
I have read chapter 5: Branch and Bound from a book called 'FOUNDATIONS OF ALGORITHMS', it's the 4th edition by Richard Neapolitan and Kumarss Naimipour , and the text is about designing algorithms, complexity analysis of algorithms, and computational complexity (analysis of problems), very interesting book, and I came across this pseudocode:

---

```
Void BeFS( state_space_tree T, number& best)

{

priority _queue-of_node PQ; 

node(u,v); 

initialize (PQ)   % initialize PQ to be empty

u=root of T;

best=value(v);

insert(PQ,v)      insert(PQ,v) is a procedure that adds v to the priority queue PQ 

  while(!empty(PQ){   % remove node with best bound

     remove(PQ,v);
```

---

```
remove(PQ,v) is a procedure that removes the node with the best bound and it assigns    its value to v
```

---

```
   if(bound(v) is better than best) % check if node is still promising

     for (each child of u of v){ 

     if (value (u) is better than best)

    (best=value(u);

     if (bound(u) is better than best)

    insert(PQ,u)
       }
      }
     }
```

---

I don't know how to code it in matlab, and branch and bound is an interesting  general algorithm for finding optimal solutions of various optimization problems, especially in discrete and combinatorial optimization, instead of using heuristics to find an optimal solution, since branch and bound reduces calculation time and finds the optimal solution faster.

## EDIT:

I have checked everywhere whether a solution already has been implemented , before posting a question here. And I came here to get ideas of how I can get started to implement this code

Comment: I don't see a question here, unless you are asking other people to implement an algorithm for you. That would not be a suitable question for this site. Please try it yourself and if you get stuck somewhere you can ask specific questions. You may also want to google to check whether a solution already has been implemented.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin Before coming here, I have checked everywhere whether a solution already has been implemented, but I couldn't find anything similar to what I'm trying to do to, to give me an Idea on how to get started. I came here to get ideas of how I can get started , I'm not asking anyone to implement an algorithm for me, and I wouldnt have come here if it wasnt my last attempt , because Im pressed with time , anyhow thank you for taking the time to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included this in your post so people can know better what you expect of them. However, 'ideas to get started to implement' is still not much more specific than 'how to write code in matlab'.

However, I will still try to answer:

1. Make the structure of the code, write the basic loops and fill them with comments of what you want to do
2. Pick (the easiest or first) one of those comments, and see whether you can make it happen in a few lines, you can test it by generating some dummy input for that piece of code
3. Keep repeating step 2 untill all comments have the required code

If you get stuck in one of the blocks, and have searched but not found the answer to a specific question. Then this is not a bad place to ask.

Comment: I already have the structure of my code, i need to figure out how to generate a priority queue in matlab, Ive come across codes that implemented a priority queue in C and then uses matlab, but I cant do that , sorry but this is final year internship project , so im pretty stressed, and didnt mean to sound like i wanted someone to implement for me.